# How to get the progress of nodejs readline or any other ways of reading a large file line by line?

Tags: node.js, file, terminal, command-line-interface

I am using [node's `readline` module](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line) to do some processing on a large file that I have to read line-by-line, and since it's huge, it takes a long time.

I need a way of monitoring and reporting the total progress of the operation (preferably with `readline`)

The `'line'` event that is emitted by the `readline`'s created `Interface` does not provide anything related to this use-case. There are also no other useful data on other events or methods of `readline`.

I couldn't also find any alternative solutions to `readline` that may have what that I need.

For example, when downloading a resource over a network (over HTTP with XHR/fetch or any TCP connection) one has access to the bytes-read of the input in the event of coming data packets and by having a bytes-total we can calculate the progress.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I wrote the last paragraph, I got the idea for a solution!

The `'line'` event emitted by the `readline`'s `Interface` is returning the line as a string and we can calculate how many bytes that string would be and use it to maintain the total-bytes-read.

Also before starting to read the file we could get the size of the file and a simple division gives us the progress for each line.

Assuming that each character in the string is one byte in size, which is not the right assumption for all cases (was for mine), I did it like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')

const input = 'my-huge-file'

const inputSize = fs.statSync(input).size

let progressDate = Date.now()
let inputRead = 0

const rl = readline.createInterface({input: fs.createReadStream(input), crlfDelay: Infinity })
rl.on('line', line => {
  inputRead += line.length+1 // also count the \n
  const now = Date.now()
  if (now-progressDate>1000) {
    process.stdout.write(`\r${Math.floor(10000*inputRead/inputSize)/100}%`)
    progressDate = now
  }

  // PROCESS the line
});
```

I've added `progressDate` to print the progress on each second (not on each line)

Comment: This is how to output progress on each line read, given the same code as above. ```rl.on('line', (line) => {
  bytesRead += line.length+1 // also count the \n;

  process.stdout.write(`\r${MMath.floor(10000 * bytesRead / fileSize) / 100}%`)```